# Системные переменные в конфиге

Tags: mysql, windows

Вопрос, можно ли в конфиге MySQL задать значение на основании системных переменных?

Что-то типа такого

```
tmpdir="%TEMP%"
```

пробовал еще так

```
tmpdir="$TEMP"
tmpdir="${TEMP}"
```

результат один

> 171120 15:57:25  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 2

`%TEMP%` взята чисто для тестирования. Реально там будет

```
tmpdir="%ALLUSERPROFILE%/MySQL/Temp"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, my.ini не поддерживает подобной функциональности. Но всегда можно запустить mysql  с командной строки, передав ему опции, значение которых как раз может быть переменными окружения. Если нужно, эти опции можно прописывать в скрипт запуска или параметры для сервиса.

Также нужно помнит, что многие переменные окружения для разных пользователей и системы разные. А большинство сервисов запускается от отдельного пользователя.

Comment: Ясно. Спасибо. Про параметры командной строки - это один из вариантов